# Не получается вывести массив в таблицу PHP

Tags: php, html, битрикс

День добрый. Есть проблема с выводом массива данных в таблицу. Вот код php

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5" cellspacing="0"
           cellpadding="0">

        <tbody>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><span>ID позиции</span></td>
            <td><span>Позиция</span></td>
            <td><span>Количество</span></td>
            <td><span>Единицы измерения</span></td>
            <td><span>Цена руб.</span></td>
   <td><span>Номер склада/места хранения</span></td>
            <td><span>Номенклатурный (инвентарный) номер</span></td>
        </tr>
        <?foreach ($applList as $item){
            $arPositionID[] = $item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE'];
        }
        $i=0;
        $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_ID", 'PROPERTY_warehouse_number', 'PROPERTY_part_numbers', 'PROPERTY_amount', 'PROPERTY_PRICE', 'PROPERTY_units', 'PROPERTY_TEHHARAKTER');
        $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_CODE"=> 'POSITION', 'ID' => $arPositionID);
        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
        while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
            $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
            $arPosition[$arFields['ID']] = $arFields;
            $i++;
        }

        ?>
        <?foreach ($applList as $item):?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_AMOUNT'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_UNITS'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$item['NAME']?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_PRICE'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_TEHHARAKTER'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_warehouse_number'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?echo $arPosition[$item['PROPERTY_POSITION_VALUE']]['PROPERTY_part_numbers'] ?>
                </td>
            </tr> 

        <?endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

На выходе массив заполняется правильно (проверял через var_dump($arPosition);) а вот в таблицу не выводит. Помогите кто сможет, в чем ошибка. Третий день бьюсь
var_dump($applList) выдает `array(0) { }`
var_dump($arPosition) тот массив который нужно вывести таблицу

```
array(8599) { [22762]=> array(22) { ["ID"]=> string(5) "22762" ["~ID"]=> string(5) "22762" ["NAME"]=> string(22) "Масса ТКП HN-1" ["~NAME"]=> string(22) "Масса ТКП HN-1" ["IBLOCK_ID"]=> string(2) "18" ["~IBLOCK_ID"]=> string(2) "18" ["PROPERTY_WAREHOUSE_NUMBER_VALUE"]=> string(4) "7801" ["~PROPERTY_WAREHOUSE_NUMBER_VALUE"]=> string(4) "7801" ["PROPERTY_WAREHOUSE_NUMBER_VALUE_ID"]=> string(7) "6535189" ["~PROPERTY_WAREHOUSE_NUMBER_VALUE_ID"]=> string(7) "6535189" ["PROPERTY_PART_NUMBERS_VALUE"]=> string(7) "2480738" ["~PROPERTY_PART_NUMBERS_VALUE"]=> string(7) "2480738" ["PROPERTY_PART_NUMBERS_VALUE_ID"]=> string(7) "6535190"
```

итд.

Comment: Вас не смущает `проверял через var_dump($arPosition);` и цикл по `$applList`?

Comment: @Visman, конечно смущает, если бы цикл по $applList что то выдавал наверняка все получилось, а так выдает var_dump выдает по этому циклу "array(0) { }". Вот и прошу вашей помощи

Comment: А в `$applList` что лежит?

Comment: Вы бы пример массивов $applList и $arPosition привели, а то из кода совершенно ни чего не ясно :)

Comment: @Visman, дополнил свой вопрос. Есть таблица уже сверстанная (в блоке битрикса лежит) а эта таблица выводится на отдельной странице как ее форма для печати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо смотреть почему $applList пустой. Естественно, если в нем ничего нет, то и foreach не фунциклирует

Comment: Я $appList заменил $arPosition, вывел имена, затем id и.т.д. в таблицу